# crop a tensor with a tensor inside a tf graph

Tags: tensorflow

I have a Tensor which needs to be cropped with the indices of a tensor.

ex - Input (None,5x5x10) tensor 
     BoundingBox (None, 2) -- tensor 
I want to have an operation that does the following 
Output (None,3x2x10) --tensor 
if BoundingBox[0,0] = 3, BoundingBox[0,1] = 2

This is same as tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box but this function does not tensor type bounding box as input. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with 'standard' tensor operations because the dimensions of the output could vary.

Consider the example where `bounding_box[0] == [3,2]` and `bounding_box[1] == [4,2]` then your output shape needs to be `(None, 3 or 4, 2, 10)` and (of course) having a dimension `3 or 4` is not allowed for standard tensors.

TensorFlow does, however, have the concept of a *Ragged* Tensor which could conceivably be used to represent crops of different dimensions but this is an unusual case and is unlikely to be suited to most mainstream downstream training operations. Still, it could be worth reading up on this to see if it fits your use case: [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors)